# LibGDX game lags when touch

Tags: android, libgdx, touch

I use `LibGDX` for rendering a game. I discovered a strange issue on `Samsung S3`. When touching a screen FPS goes down and animation jumps.
On other devices the app works smoothly. Touch callback is very fast and shouldn't affect a performance.

For adding touch support I use

```
Stage stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Could you please advice what might be the root of the issue?

Comment: Were the other devices that you tested on more powerful than the GS3? If so, it could just be that the GS3 isn't powerful enough.

Comment: @IntegralOfTan yes, tested on S2. Works perfectly.

Comment: Logically, there shouldn't be anything wrong as the touch support code is general and not device-specific or anything. I can't think of any other explanation other than the device having an issue. I really don't think it's an issue with your code.

Comment: @IntegralOfTan ,lol GS3 may be old but lagging when you touch the screen?Even my old windows mobile phone doesn't do this.He is propably doing something wrong when he plays the jump animation,like making a new object every time the user touches the screen .

Comment: @Taras ,post the code from where you make the jump animation

Comment: @SteveL hi Steve, thanks, for your comment. I should close the question, the problem was the enabled Show touches in Dev Options of the device. It decreased FPS :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Posting the answer in order to help others..

When enabling Show Touches setting in Developer Options be aware that it might decrease FPS of your game. It was my case.